# Unable to hide the text for select element and display dropdown toggle arrow on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, usability

I am trying to display only the dropdown toggle[arrow] and hide the content even after choosing other selects. But I am unable to position the dropdown toggle to center align and can see the select text appearing in the toggle background. Here is the code snippet: http://jsbin.com/ramefig/2/edit?html,css,output
It works fine on other browsers, but the styling breaks on IE[11v] alone.

Comment: For IE11 ,`select{
  width: 23px;
  border-style: none;
}`

Comment: The select I am using is to toggle between the tabs, my requirement is something like the tab in the link http://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/angularjs/tabstrip/tabstrip-switch-between-tabs-using-combobox.aspx And for this I am trying to avoid the content for the toggle and display the toggle arrow alone.

Comment: This seems to work in IE and Chrome http://jsbin.com/zepiwecaqa/edit?html,css,output .